# Windows 2003 Dynamic Disk error

Tags: windows-server-2003, partition, hard-drive, dynamic

I was trying to ghost a partition on a Windows 2003 server, using Ghost 2003.  Unfortunately things went horribly wrong, and now I can't boot back into my system.

As you can see, Ghost creates a wee little partition to do its dirty work, and has dislodged my other partitions.  Partition 2 in the image below is my C drive. Any suggestions as to how I might get this active again so that it boots?

Cheers,

Chris

[image: Ghost]

Comment: Any luck with this?

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem on workstations. I think what I did was stick fdisk on a bootable disk, boot to that, and mark the Windows partition as the active partition and the ghost partition as inactive or delete it.

Comment: Hi Dustin - I had tried that, which got the Windows boot screen to come up, but it only showed for about a second before it automatically rebooted.  We ended up rebuilding the system anyways, but now that I'm looking at my screen shot again, it looks like C: was assiged to my tape backup media. I don't suppose you know how I might get C: assigned back to the original partition?

Comment: Off the top of my head I'm not sure, but I figure there should be something in fdisk that would let you do that. If you have the ability, and if you want to know for future reference, create a VM (could probably use XP since an extra license for 2k3 is unlikely), give it a few partitions, and start up fdisk and see what all you can do from there.

Answer (score 0):

I usually ghost from a boot disk, so I haven't seen this scenario. But I believe you would boot to the recovery console and use [diskpart](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300415) to make it active again.